# How L={ww^Rx| where w, x belongs to {a,b}^* } is a regular language?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory, finite-automata, automata-theory

I have understood that L={wxw^r|w,x belongs to {a,b}^* } is regular because it turns out to be the pattern of starting and ending with same symbol but I am not getting the proper explanation that how to say L={ww^rx|w,x belongs to {a,b}*} is regular language using DFA design.
Please help me in understanding this!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about computer programming. It's about the theory of regular languages.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick question. The language L as you have specified is the language of the regular expression `(a + b)*`, that is, any string of a's and b's. The trick is that for any string `y = s1.s2.s3...sk` where `si in {a, b}`, we can write `y = wxw^R` where `w` is the empty string and `x = y`. Basically, the trick is that we can always choose `w` to be the empty string, and in that case we are left with `L = {x | x in {a, b}^*}`, clearly regular. Another way of thinking about it is this: can you find any string of a's and b's that is not in L? Is it not in L even if you take w to be the empty string?

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation  got the point that we can’t find even a single string of a’s and b’s that doesn’t belongs to langauge specified even if we consider w as empty string.That’s why this language can be represented by regualr expression (a+b)*